# why does console.log() show the new value even when I call it before the I update the array?

Tags: javascript, object, reference

I have `MyObject{internalArray:["ds","sdfs"]}`

Then I call `console.log(MyObject.internalArray)`

Then I do `MyObject.internalArray.push("weird?")`

I expect output: `["ds","sdfs"]`

Why do I get output: `["ds","sdfs","weird?"]`

Is it something to do with hoisting?

Comment: Thanks. Would never have figured that out in a million light years.